# How to start the MediaRecorder in Android 4.0

Tags: android, camera

Hi iam using MediaRecordor class to record the video.The code is as below

MediaRecorder recorder=new MediaRecorder();

recorder.start();

The above line recorder.start() working fine in Android 2.x versions but the same line when executing in Android 4.0 the app is crashing.Any suggesstions.

Thanks&Regards,

Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is connected with device characteristics. Try to play with setting different fps, videoRate, resolution, so on.
Also check your steps for initialization MediaRecorder, because it works as a state machine.
Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html